# Allow users to edit their account when using omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im allowing users to signup through omniauth on my rails app, and that is working successfully. I'm creating the login and registration process through a controller called sessions.

However I would like them to be able to edit their user information. As I'm making them sign up through Twitter, the next step is asking them for their email.

How do I go about creating a controller for account settings, that doesn't end up having a path such as url.com/user/:id/edit - instead I prefer it to be clean, like what devise does with simply user/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you have a User model you will want to add appropriate controller and view code to allow users to edit information. Here is a repo/sample app I did a while back. Its for devise, but it may be helpful:

https://github.com/marklocklear/devise-roles-user-management

Good luck!